# Drupal 7 content structure

Tags: drupal-7, structure, contenttype

I am working on a project with drupal 7. My drupal experience is limited and Im a bit stuck on how to achieve a good structure.

The site will have products like wine, sherries and spirits. Each of these product types will have subcategories. (example: like red / white wine) Within these subcategories there will be certain brands of wines.

Since the website is focussing only on displaying the products and not selling them, I really do not want to use any ecommerce software, or modules.

Preferably I would like the products to be a content type. There is a little catch to it. All categories, so in the examples above; wines, sherries, spirits BUT ALSO red / white wines should have a description and a image.

Can anyone shed some light on how to create this in drupal 7. I have googled a lot but im not sure what the right approach would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create the different pages using the taxonomy structure and views. You would set up a custom content type of products, then for each product put in the proper tags.  This should group together the different categories for you.